# How to export image in powerpoint using asp.net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core

I have to export some images into powerpoint (.ppt or .pptx format) using asp.net core 2.0. Any ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use [SlideMight](http://www.slidemight.com), a data merge tool for PowerPoint.

You should be able to get 1 slide per image, or 1 table row per image, or 1 table cell, or so. You can also make a thumbnail slide that links to 15 detail slides. You define this in a "pattern file", which is much like a PowerPoint template.

Your asp.net program should write the images to the file system, or have URLs available. It should also create an input data file (XML, JSON or YAML) that refers to these images. Then it should invoke SlideMight to generate the desired presentation. Normally SlideMight runs in a GUI. It should also be able to run as a command line program, although this has not been tested lately (please let me know if you need it).

Would this be of use?

Disclaimer: I am the developer and vendor of SlideMight.